# How to include transparency in html/css?

Tags: html, css, transparency, transparent

I now need my search bar and button to be slightly transparent... kinda like twitters when the mouse is not hovering over it. How do i do this in html/css?
**CSS:**

```
.search1{
    position: absolute;
    font-family:"Arial Unicode MS";
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    border-style:none     
}

.search2{
    position: absolute;
    border-style:none;
    font-family:"Arial Unicode MS";
    color:black;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    font-size:xx-large 
}  

input:hover{
    background-color:white;
    border-color:white;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form class="search2" method="get" action="default.html" />
<input class="search2" type="text" name="serach_bar" size="31" maxlength="255"       
value="" style="left: 396px; top: 149px; width: 300px; height: 50px;" />
<input class="search1" type="submit" name="submition" value="Search" style=" padding-    bottom:20px; left: 710px; top: 157px; height: 17px" />
<input class="search2" type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="default.html" />
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: why don't you first go to your previous questions and accept it? read the faq at http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work with every browser including IE6

```
div {
 -khtml-opacity:.50; 
 -moz-opacity:.50; 
 -ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=50)";
  filter:alpha(opacity=50);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0.5);
  opacity:.50; 
}
```

### see working example at http://jsfiddle.net/vnj4s/3/

Comment: thanks for all the help but when i put 'filter' or 'opacity' in it says that 'This is not supported in the current schema'

Comment: rgba is not supported in allot of browsers. Read http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/. The solution i provided will work with every browser.

Comment: ok... ive been looking through my settings and the only thing i can see about css is the scema selection and ive currently got css 2.1... is that the right one?

Comment: oh sorry im new to this how do i do that?

Answer (score 3):

CSS 3 introduces [colour values with alpha channels](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgba-color), but you need to mix in images for backwards compatibility. http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/alpha-colour/ has a guide.

If you want the foreground too, then use [opacity](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html) instead (it needs hacking for some versions of IE).

Answer (score 1):

Use the

```
 opacity
```

property.... (the filter is for IE)

try

```
#element{
     opacity:.5;
     filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
   }
```

and

```
#element:hover{
    opacity:1;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 100);
}
```

Comment: make sure you are applying it to a block level element with a defined width and height

Comment: Sam, by "don't work" do mean it doesn't validate? Because often hacks like this will not.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the opacity.  You'll need to add filter: alpha so it works in IE browsers.

Something like this

```
.searchBar {opacity: .7; filter:alpha(opacity=70);}
.searchBar:hover {opacity: 1; filter:alpha(opacity=100);}
```

Here's a link explaining it http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use `opacity`:

```
opacity:0.5
```

And IE's Filter:

```
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
```

**Or** the CSS3 RGBA Colors:

```
background-color:RGBA(0,0,0,0.5);
```

Comment: maybe its my css settings or something but it just wont work when i put opacity in...

Comment: is richness the same thing in css?

Comment: Wait, which browser do you have? And what element are you applying the opacity to?

Comment: internet explorer 8 or something and im sorry but i dont know what you mean by elemet (sorry im kinda a noob at css!)

Comment: The HTML element (ex `<input>` or `<form>`), I'm guessing you should apply it to one of the `<input>` ones...Also, make sure you added `filter:alpha(opacity=50);`